# Using AR_Extensions' finders to specify "not_in"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm trying to use AR-Extensions finders without success:

My code:

```
Post.all(:conditions=>{:updated_at_not_in=>2.weeks.ago..Date.today}}
```

I get "updated_at_not_in: unknown column".

Anything I am missing?

p.s.
In the Post model I have required:

```
require 'ar-extensions'
require 'ar-extensions/adapters/mysql'
require 'ar-extensions/import/mysql'
```

I'm using MySQL, Rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to skirt around the issue. I haven't had time to investigate what you're getting, but this syntax is no longer available as you upgrade to Rails 3.x. I have removed it from activerecord-import and have no plans to introduce it as its own gem. When I first wrote this code in 2006 I was hoping to inspire the rails-core team to introduce a more pluggable architecture for having better finders across database adapters, but it never took. I apologize for any time you spent with this issue.